# Custom messages working in GUI version but not CLI

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Using Jmeter version 5.2.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 we have a number of tests we run and some of them have custom messages.  Below is the code.

```
<ResponseAssertion guiclass="AssertionGui" testclass="ResponseAssertion" testname="C01 - ${marsha} Current Date" enabled="true">
    <collectionProp name="Asserion.test_strings">
        <stringProp name="1193219718">unsuccessfulSell=true</stringProp>
    </collectionProp>
    <stringProp name="Assertion.custom_message">C01 - ${marsha} Current Date - Product Not Available</stringProp>
    <stringProp name="Assertion.test_field">Assertion.sample_label</stringProp>
    <boolProp name="Assertion.assume_success">false</boolProp>
    <intProp name="Assertion.test_type">6</intProp>
</ResponseAssertion>
```

When we run this in the GUI version we get something like the following:

```
C01 - abzcy Current Date - Product Not Available
```

When we run the same test with the CLI we get no message at all.  Originally I thought it was working but I was seeing the wrong column.

Any thoughts?

Attached is a screenshot of the rule I'm referring to.

[Screenshot of assertion screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kPJH.png)

The custom message does not come out at all.

For other assertions we do not have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue given this [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) Configuration:

[image]

When I [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) as follows:

```
./jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

I can see the custom assertion failure message in the *result.jtl* file

[image]

Any chance you have customized [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)? In particular `jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message` property needs to be set to `true`

Comment: Also, I set jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=true and it's still not outputting the custom message.

Comment: One thing to note:  My test is not a Text Response.  In our case we are using URL Sampled as the field to test.  Our custom messages for Text Response and Response Code assertions work fine.